# Convert TwoLetterIsoCode Country Code

Tags: c#, country

I wanted to ask if there is a clean and fast way to convert a TwoLetterIsoCode into the english name accordingly using C#?

An example:

```
US -> United Staates

DE -> Germany

FR -> France
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var displayName = new RegionInfo(twoLettersIsoCode).EnglishName
```

The RegionInfo class is described in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just found it out myself aswell :)

```
 private static string GetCountryName(string CountryCode)
        {
            RegionInfo RegInfo = new RegionInfo(CountryCode);
            return RegInfo.EnglishName;
        }
```

Comment: And you couldn't have done that five minute ago before you asked the question?

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that helped you to write this method.